# Build both 32-bit and 64-bit versions for 64-bit platform

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, build, project

I have a MSVC++ project which can be built targeting a 32-bit or 64-bit platform. When targeting 64-bit, I need the 32-bit version to be built as well (it produces a type library which needs to be registered for both 32-bit and 64-bit consumers).

Is it possible to configure the project to build the 32-bit target when the chosen platform is Win32, and both the 64-bit and 32-bit targets when the chosen platform is x64?

Comment: If you want to do this from the IDE, you'll need two projects:  One to build the 32-bit binaries and one to build the 64-bit binaries.

Comment: I'd probably break the building of the TLB into a separate utility project, and make the main project (both configurations) depend on it.